# Remove all words containing '@' from list in DataFrame

Tags: regex, python-3.x, list, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame in which one column contains lists of words.

```
>>dataset.head(1)
>>               contain
  0            ["name", "Place", "ect@gtr", "nick"]
  1            ["gf@e", "nobel", "play", "hi"]
```

I want to remove all the words which contain `'@'`. In the above example, I want to remove `"ect@gtr"` and `"gf@e"`.

Comment: Are you using python `pandas`?

Answer (score 0):

Try This one

```
ab= np.column_stack([~df[col].str.contains(r"@") for col in df])
new_df=df.loc[ab.any(axis=1)]
print(new_df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `list comprehension` with filtering, regex here is not necessary:

```
df =  pd.DataFrame({'contain':[['name', 'Place', 'ect@gtr', 'nick'],
                               ['gf@e', 'nobel', 'play', 'hi']]})
print (df)
                        contain
0  [name, Place, ect@gtr, nick]
1       [gf@e, nobel, play, hi]

df.contain = df.contain.apply(lambda x: [y for y in x if '@' not in y])
```

Or:

```
df.contain = [[y for y in x if '@' not in y] for x in df.contain]

print (df)
               contain
0  [name, Place, nick]
1    [nobel, play, hi]
```

EDIT: For remove values in strings add `split` with `join`:

```
df =  pd.DataFrame({'contain':['name Place ect@gtr nick',"gf@e nobel play hi"]})
print (df)

                   contain
0  name Place ect@gtr nick
1       gf@e nobel play hi

df.contain = df.contain.apply(lambda x: ' '.join([y for y in x.split() if '@' not in y]))
print (df)
           contain
0  name Place nick
1    nobel play hi
```

Comment: its worked, what if i have a string like "name Place ect@gtr nick" and now i want to remove ect@gtr?

Comment: @ImranAhmadGhazali - do you think instaed `["name", "Place", "ect@gtr", "nick"]` is `"name Place ect@gtr nick" ` or `["name", "Place", "ect@gtr", "nick"]` is like `["name", "Place", "ect@gtr", "name Place ect@gtr nick"]` ?

Comment: no , both are the difference, actually, i have a string like this "name Place ect@gtr nick". previously i was changing it token like ["name", "Place", "ect@gtr", "nick"].  so want to know both the answer